# how to check function is called in react error?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am getting error while testing `axios.get` function in `react`

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/oq7kwzrnj5

```
it("check ajax call", () => {
      jest.mock('axios', () => {
        const exampleArticles:any = {
          data :{
            data:['A','B','c']
          }
        }
        return {
          get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(exampleArticles)),
        };
      });


    expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

[image]

any update ?? no solution

Answer (score 0):

I've found this information in [jest-mock-axios](https://github.com/knee-cola/jest-mock-axios#why-do-we-need-to-manually-create-the-mock):

> **Why do we need to manually create the mock?**
>
> It's because Jest expects mocks to be placed in the project root,
>   while packages
>   installed via NPM get stored inside node_modules subdirectory.

Maybe that's why you can't use `jest.mock` and there are packages like above to solve that.